# How to get words from quicktype of default keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, uikeyinput

I have custom TextView to edit text with simple UIKeyInput.

When I select word from quick type suggestions it sends empty string to 

`- (void) insertText:(NSString *)text`

How to get word from quick type?

[image]